# Strange WCF net.tcp exception

Tags: wcf, tcp, wcf-security

I have a WCF client/service with net.tcp transport. When I turn on the WCF tracing on client side I am seeing the following errors in trace (see screenshot from service trace viewer). The strange thing is that WCF is handling and recovering this error and my client doesn't receive any exception and it continues to work. This exception happens freqently, randomly but not on every web method call. 
The client (windows XP) authentication is windows, service is identified by SPN, services are self-hosted on windows service behind an NLB (windows server 2003).
Can anyone explain me what is happening here.

The exception stacktrace from the trace xml is:

```
<ExceptionString>
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The server rejected the upgrade request. ---&gt; System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: Error while reading message framing format at position 0 of stream (state: ReadingUpgradeRecord) ---&gt; System.IO.InvalidDataException: More data was expected, but EOF was reached.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
</ExceptionString>
```

[image: Screenshot]:

Comment: As a background, some of our users were reporting many exceptions and I was investigating why only some of the PCs seem to have it. So I started a service trace on my own PC and I was surprised as these exceptions are never received by the client, WCF is gobbling them.
I am thinking if this MessageSecurityException is eventually causing some of the client to get real exceptions.
Some clients log this exception:
Could not connect to net.tcp://myservice:9501/SomeService. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.3873440. TCP error code 10060:

Comment: You mentioned NLB. Do you use sticky sessions (session affinity)?

Comment: No the NLB session affinity is none in port rules. The service is using a custom net.tcp binding with 2 min idletimeout and 1 min leasetimeout. However I found that that we are using persession instancecontextmode accidentally because someone thought this is the default. I will change this to percall very soon.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure what the real problem could be and if it's related to streaming (I'll dive in). Anyway you can try catch the exception on the server side and throw a *CommunicationException* instead.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new CommunicationException(ex.Message, ex);
}
```

This way the client proxy should not ignore the exception and it's state should be "Faulted".